# VSTS - Access customization process

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

[VSTS Organization Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is84J.png)I am using VSTS for our Organization. I am seeing the following access/Security groups.
**1.Basic
2.Stakeholder
3.Visual Studio Professional Subscription
4.Visual Studio Subscriber**

I am adding different users to different groups and everybody is able to create the new organization which is weird.
Is there anyway that we can limit the users developer to use specified group and admins to use some other group?
Can also specify what kind of limitations we have for basic, stakeholder, VS Professional and VS Subscriber?
Thanks in advance..

GSR

Comment: What do you mean by *everybody is able to create the new organization*? What is an *organization* in this context?

Comment: Everybody able to access(Basic,Stakeholder,VS Professional Subscription, VS Subscriber) "create own VSTS organization" in our environment. They can create own team project under the "new organization" and able to code and build,Work items and check-in and deploy to own Azure account

Answer (score 1):

You can add people to team projects, rather than to your organization. VSTS automatically assigns them Basic features, if your organization has seats available, or Stakeholder features, if not. Learn [how to add members to team projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/add-team-members-vs?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cprevious-nav).

Access levels enable administrators the ability to provide their user base access to the features they need and only pay for those features.

- Five users who get Basic features, such as version control, tools for
  Agile, Java, build, release management, and more
- Unlimited users who get Stakeholder features, such as working with
  your backlog, work items, and queries
- Unlimited Visual Studio subscribers who also get Basic features, and
  in some cases, additional features with specific extensions, such as
  Test Manager

More information, you can refer to the articles below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users-from-user-hub?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/access-levels?view=vsts

Comment: Thank you Cece!! I knew about the basic, stake holder & etc. access levels. I just want check with you how  can we restrict access for  the creating new VSTS Organization?  All the people in my team were able to create it and became the owner for that VSTS Organization

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. All the users can create their own organizations(VSTS Account). Every organization is an independent VSTS Account. You cannot restrict the access for this.

Comment: Thanks Eddie! What if someone create organization and create team project then code,deploy Company data to his personal azure portal? How can we restrict an individual stop doing that? And also what kind of things we can do after creating new organization in VSTS in our company's domain?

Comment: @GSR Even without new organization, the user can copy company data via other method if he want. So this depends on how do you manage your users.